# Is my question really too broad? How could I improve it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, deleted-questions

My question [Send default 404 error page when Referer does not match](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/25221/16414) got "closed as too broad" by a moderator and "deleted by Community ♦", eight months after I asked it. As far as I can see, it got no votes/answers/comments.

I assume missing votes and answers are the reason why I got deleted after it got closed. But **why was it closed** in the first place? Is it really too broad? If so, how could I improve it?

---

Here’s the question for those that cannot see deleted content:

> #### Send default 404 error page when Referer does not match
>
> Coming from [this question on IT Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/33942/12139), I want to do the following in `.htaccess` for Apache:
>
> If the `Referer` is NOT `SecretString`, send HTTP status 404 with the default (= *not* a custom) error page.
>
> The error page should be exactly the same one you get when visiting a non-existent file on a host without any website resp. custom error pages set up.
>
> The following `.htaccess` seems to work fine:
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^SecretString$
> RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]
> ```
>
> **Could this be improved resp. be done in a different way?**
>
> The Apache documentation says about the [`R` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r):
>
> > *Any* valid HTTP response status code may be specified, using the syntax [R=305], with a 302 status code being used by default if none is specified. The status code specified need not necessarily be a redirect (3xx) status code. However, if a status code is outside the redirect range (300-399) then the substitution string is dropped entirely, and rewriting is stopped as if the *L* were used.
>
> I'm not sure if I understand the last sentence correctly. Does this mean that when using the value `404`, Apache simply ignores whatever you specify at the third position (here: `-`)? And I could omit the `L` flag then too, correct?
>
> ```
> RewriteRule .* - [R=404]
> ```
>
> Should I specify something else than `-`? Or is this the correct character for "nothing"?
>
> Does `.*` really mean "everything" (*all* URLs) or is there something better?
>
> Is using `R=404` the correct way to send the default 404 page?

Tagged: [.htaccess](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than *too broad*, I would say that a more appropriate closure reason would be *off-topic*.  This is a how-can-I-accomplish-this question, not a request for a code review.

I think the most appropriate Stack Exchange site for this question would be [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/404+mod-rewrite).  I can't migrate the question for you, since it's too old.

Comment: But the included code *works*. I’d like to know if it could be improved and if I’m using the mentioned parts correctly or if I’m "misusing" them. Would it be bettter if I’d remove the second part (everyting after "Could this be improved …")?

Comment: Fair enough. I've reopened the question.